# Calling function directly in for loop

Tags: c#

I have seen people write code like below example,

```
foreach (DataRow row in GetStudentData(studentID).Rows)
{
    //do something
}
```

Can you advise if this is a acceptable/good practise to call a function (GetStudentData function) directly instead of assigning it to a variable and then using it?

Comment: Usually I'd put it into a variable for debugging purpose, but it really doesn't make a difference execution-wise. This does not belong here though as it's partially off topic or too broad to have an answer. It'll mostly be personal opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking it is not forbidden to do it like that, but please take into considerations following issues:

- as already mentioned in the comments, if you have problems with this part of code, you'd like to see what does the method return - here it will be rather a hard topic, so storing the result first and then enumerating it would be more convenient
- you'd maybe want to check if the result is not null before acccessing `.Rows` from the result? Might be impossible here (from C# 6 it's already doable with ?. operator)
- generally speaking any conditional logic on the result of the method would be a difficult topic.
- this actually  might be more a personal opinion, but chaining consecutive calls in the foreach statement looks ugly and makes this code less readable. So as long as it's `GetStudents(studentID).Rows`,maybe it's not SO bad. But as people tend to go the easier way, once you make it a 'good practice', I can already imagine statements like `foreach(student in GetStudents(studentID).Rows.FirstOrDefault(stud => stud.GetFirstName()...`

So I would say, there's more 'no' than 'yes'.

What is interesting, is that the IL generated for both this code and corresponding

```
var students = GetStudentData(studentID);
foreach (DataRow row in students.Rows)
{
       //do something
}
```

should be more, or less the same, so at the end of the day, CLR doesn't care.